# Is it possible to implement a fading effect for the Toolbar title in Android Studio, where the title slowly fades away as the user scrolls?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-xml

Below is my **custom toolbar**, where i want the title name to **slowly fade** its color when **Scrolled Up** and it should also come back to its initial color slowly when **Scrolled Down**.

is it possible to do it in XML?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="TITLE"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" /> 
   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Below is another **XML file** where i included above layout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/black">

  <include layout="@layout/custom_collapsing_toolbar"/>

  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```